# Cron Job to run a simple link (No experience with Cron Jobs at all)

Tags: php, cron

I am fairly certain this is an extremely easy thing to do for more of the experienced users, and probably shouldn't take more than a minute to do.
Unfortunately I have no experience with Cron Jobs, and despite reading documentation I can't seem to find any info on how to accomplish this.

I need to set up a Cron job to run every day at a certain time (This much I already know the syntax for), and what it needs to run is an "Export" link on my website that I use for product feeds.

The link is:
    http://www.heroesofgc.com/index.php?route=feed/bidorbuystoreintegrator/export&t=73f6176e946fe85c5fb230b6040466d0

What command would I need to use to get it to work?

-I've read about using 'Wget', but I don't believe I have any such thing on my server at the moment (or don't know where to find its path at least).

Comment: Do you have SSH access with user `root` or Administrator? Is it a windows or linux server?

Comment: Hi, Sorry to sound so ignorant - but I'm not sure. I can provide some of my hosting details if it helps: I'm using a Shared hosting package from "WebhostingBuzz" and they have an area where you can set up Cron Jobs in the cPanel via a GUI, after selecting a time and frequency you then simply put the command you wish to run in the "Command" field - that's where I'm stuck as I'm pretty sure just placing the link will do nothing. I alos don't understand how to use the 'Wget' command, is there something extra I need to copy to my server for that? I have ftp access if I need it.

Comment: Oh... ok try putting `curl -I http://....` in that input box.

Answer (score 1):

Here shown, how you can set cronjob timing

http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference

http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab

Comment: Answers containing links but no example or explanation are likely to be closed.